# Convert a two variable function from one variable to the other

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm writing a simulator for a museum. I have a function of the form:

```
$$P = .5TV[{\frac(2T)(ARV^2) + 1}^1/2 + 1]$$
```

Which solves for P given variable T (as well as A, V, and R).

I would like to rearrange the equation such that it solves for T given variable P (and the other variables). The best I could do is:

```
$$T = [2PAR(P - TV)]^1/3$$
```

....but obviously T is on both sides. Is it possible to make this a function of only P (and A, V, R)?

If not possible, what is such an equation called (i.e. cannot be made into a function of a given variable)?

Also, what is the best (fast, efficient) way to solve for T? Currently I am iterating to find the solution, starting with T=0 and continuing until the change in T is less than some small constant.

Thanks
--jon

Comment: It would be a lot easier to read if you format this with [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If your last expression is correct, raise each side to the third power to face a cubic equation in $T$; if the other parameters are all positive, there is only one real root which has a rather simple expression. Could you rewrite the first equation (which is not very clear) ?

Comment: Well, I tried editing my original post to use MathJax. That was a failure, as you can see. What do I need so that the "$$" get interpreted as "this is an equation"?

As for what exactly I want, I thought that was pretty clear: I have an equation that solves for P given T. I want an equation that instead solves for T given P.

As for cube root solutions I am trying to dredge the depths of my brain for something I learned 5 decades ago. Will do more research on roots and such:-)